# Understand Typescript syntax around Type assertions/casting

Tags: typescript, mongoose, casting, assertion, extending-classes

I'm a newbie to TypeScript.

I've been looking to find elegant patterns to define Mongoose schemas using TypeScript.  I've been studying an article by Nicholas Mordecai at:

https://know-thy-code.com/mongoose-schemas-models-typescript/

It's a very helpful (thanks Nicholas)!  There are though a few coding conventions I just can't get to the bottom of.  The first relates to the following chunk of code ...

```
import { Schema, model, Document, Model } from 'mongoose';

declare interface IContact extends Document{
    name: string;
    email: string;
    phone?: string;
    message?: string;
    course_enquiry?: string;
    creation_date: Date;
}

export interface ContactModel extends Model<IContact> {};
```

The specific bit that's confusing me is:

```
 "Model<IContact> {};"
```

Of course, I can't even look at the generated js code because interfaces don't get transpiled.

ContactModel extends IContact, but only after IContact has been re-asserted/cast (from a Mongoose Document) to a Mongoose Model.  Have I assumed correctly here?  What's stumping me is simply what the code convention ...

```
"Class<interface> {};"
```

actually does/achieves!

The second question relates to the following piece of code, which Nicholas has contained within the same ts file as the above:

```
export class Contact {

    private _model: Model<IContact>;

    constructor() {
        const schema =  new Schema({
            name: { type: String, required: true },
            email: { type: String, required: true },
            phone: { type: String },
            message: { type: String },
            course_enquiry: { type: String },
            creation_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
        });

        this._model = model<IContact>('User', schema);
    }

    public get model(): Model<IContact> {
        return this._model
    }
}
```

The bit I would appreciate help on in here is the assessor get method...

```
public get model(): Model<IContact> {
        return this._model
}
```

I understand the principle of get assessors but I'm not sure whether the code after "model():" is returning a function or an instance of this._model (or both)?

Also, in a separate ts controller file, Nicholas uses the following two pieces of code to use the above...

```
import { connect, connection, Connection } from 'mongoose';
import { Contact, ContactModel } from './../models/contactsModel';

declare interface IModels {
    Contact: ContactModel;

}
```

```
        this._models = {
            Contact: new Contact().model
            // this is where we initialise all models
        }
```

NB.  this._models is defined as "private _models: IModels;"

I'd really love to understand specifically and in detail what this code is doing!  My interpretation is that a new Contact object is being created, which then uses the get assessor method model(), which returns an IContact interface (cast/asserted as a Model)??

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Model<IContact>`, you are seeing a **Generic Class**.
See the Docs about them [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes).

> In languages like C# and Java (and tsc) , one of the main tools in the toolbox for creating reusable components is *generics*, that is, being able to create a component that can work over a variety of types rather than a single one. This allows users to consume these components and use their own types.

> A generic class has a similar shape to a generic interface. Generic classes have a generic type parameter list in angle brackets (<>) following the name of the class.

> Just as with interface, putting the type parameter on the class itself lets us make sure all of the properties of the class are working with the same type.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I shall go and do further research on generics and may com back with a follow-up